# Query to get the Average of ONLY the first occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables like these:

**Table Info**

```
 id | created_date
  1 | 2020-07-12 11:00:00
  2 | 2020-08-12 10:00:00
  3 | 2020-09-14 02:00:00
  4 | 2020-09-16 12:00:00
  5 | 2020-09-18 17:00:00
  6 | 2020-09-22 13:00:00
  7 | 2020-10-22 12:00:00
...
```

**Table A**

```
 id | IndoId | occurrency_date
  1 |  Info1 | 2020-07-22 11:00:00
  2 |  Info1 | 2021-05-12 11:00:00
  3 |  Info1 | 2020-08-12 12:00:00
  4 |  Info2 | 2021-03-12 21:00:00
  5 |  Info2 | 2021-02-12 01:00:00
  6 |  Info2 | 2020-07-12 12:00:00
  7 |  Info3 | 2020-10-22 17:00:00
...
```

I need to take the first occurrence (`occurrency_date` ordered asc) of each Info and subtract from when the Info was created (`created_date`), after that take the average between them

Something like this:

```
AVG(
 (Info1 created date - Info1 first occurrence) + 
 (Info2 created date - Info2 first occurrence) + 
 (Info3 created date - Info3 first occurrence) + ...
)
```

I made many attempts but none were successful, how could I get this data?

Comment: How you are relating two tables? is infoid of table A= 'info'+id of table info?

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Comment: the relation between two tables is not clear, for example : How can I know when the Info 1 was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, you just need to get the `min(occurrency_date)`  of each `info_id` and with  subquery get their `crated_date`:

```
WITH j (info_id,val) AS (
 SELECT info_id,
  (SELECT created_date 
   FROM info WHERE id = a.info_id) - min(occurrency_date)
 FROM a
 GROUP BY info_id)
SELECT avg(val) FROM j;
```

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly, thanks!
If I wanted to take just the third occurrence or just the fifth occurrence, I would have some way to do that without using `min()`

Comment: @HumbertoVieira nice it helped. If you need specific rows, you might wanna take a look at: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Comment: Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
   create table info (id int, created_date date);
   insert into info values(1 , '2020-07-12 11:00:00');
   insert into info values(2 , '2020-08-12 10:00:00');
   insert into info values(3 , '2020-09-14 02:00:00');
   insert into info values(4 , '2020-09-16 12:00:00');
   insert into info values(5 , '2020-09-18 17:00:00');
   insert into info values(6 , '2020-09-22 13:00:00');
   insert into info values(7 , '2020-10-22 12:00:00');

   create table table_a(id int, InfoId varchar(50), occurrency_date date);
   insert into table_a values(1 ,  'Info1' , '2020-07-22 11:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(2 ,  'Info1' , '2021-05-12 11:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(3 ,  'Info1' , '2020-08-12 12:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(4 ,  'Info2' , '2021-03-12 21:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(5 ,  'Info2' , '2021-02-12 01:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(6 ,  'Info2' , '2020-07-12 12:00:00');
   insert into table_a values(7 ,  'Info3' , '2020-10-22 17:00:00');
```

Query#1 (with group by and aggregation):

```
 select avg(difference) from
 (
     select  (min(created_date)- min(occurrency_date)) difference
     from info i inner join table_a a on concat('Info',i.id)=a.InfoId
     group by a.infoid
 )t
```

Output:

| avg |
| --- |
| -5.6666666666666667 |

Query#2 for first occurence date(with row_number()over() ranking window function and common table expression)

```
 with occurences as 
 (
     select infoid, occurrency_date, row_number()over(partition by infoid order by occurrency_date)rn
     from table_a
 )
 
     select  avg(created_date- occurrency_date )
     from info i inner join occurences o on concat('Info',i.id)=o.InfoId
     where rn=1
```

Output:

| avg |
| --- |
| -5.6666666666666667 |

Query#2 for second occurence date(with row_number()over() ranking window function and common table expression)

```
 with occurences as 
 (
     select infoid, occurrency_date, row_number()over(partition by infoid order by occurrency_date)rn
     from table_a
 )
 
     select  avg(created_date- occurrency_date )
     from info i inner join occurences o on concat('Info',i.id)=o.InfoId
     where rn=2
```

Output:

| avg |
| --- |
| -107.5000000000000000 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd41d9953e75ca66da7deef5be0404f4)*

Comment: I would need the return to be an interval of time, and `created_date` should not be `min(created_date)` , I tried to modify the db<>fiddle, but it didn't work

Comment: Since you have one created_date for each info it will return that. since i have use group by i had to use aggregation. You need to pick second or third occurrence which is achievable through row_number(). But let me know one thing first is id of info = infoid of table_a or concat('Info',i.id)=a.InfoId?

Comment: @HumbertoVieira please look into query#1 and query#2 by simply selecting rn =1 or rn=2 you can select occurency_date of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions to solve this.  However, I'm not sure if you want this:

```
select avg(i.created_date - min_od)
from (select i.*,
             min(a.occurency_date) over (partition by a.indoid) as min_od
      from info i join
           a
           on a.id = i.id
     ) i;
```

Or:

```
select ( avg(created_date - min_od) filter where indoid = 'info1') +
         avg(created_date - min_od) filter where indoid = 'info2') +
         avg(created_date - min_od) filter where indoid = 'info3')
       ) 
from (select i.*, a.indoid,
             min(a.occurency_date) over (partition by a.indoid) as min_od
      from info i join
           a
           on a.id = i.id
     ) i;
```